# How to fix cx_freeze macos application error (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cx-freeze

I'm making a game for my friend and I am using cx_freeze to turn it into a standalone application to run. I run the setup.py script in the game directory using:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_dmg
```

or:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_mac
```

and it creates a folder with the application, however when I run the application I get an error that mac couldn't run it..

Here's my setup.py script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

#buildOptions = dict(include_files = [(absolute_path_to_your_file,'final_filename')]) #single file, absolute path.

buildOptions = dict(include_files = ['assets/'])

#tells cx_freeze to include everything in the assets folder when making the applicatino


setup(
         name = "Cookie Clicker",
         version = "Beta-0.1",
         description = "Simple Cookie Clicker Game",
         author = "n/a",
         options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
         executables = [Executable("cookieclicker.py", base=base)])
```

It says it cannot open this file........... TIA

Comment: Are you freezing on a Mac for Mac? Which version are you using (python / cx_freeze). Did you search SO? There are some answers in which the setup scripts look more or less slightly different.

Comment: Yes, freezing for a mac on a mac, python is version 3.8.5, cx_freeze is version 6.2. I've looked around, seems to just be me.........

Comment: This only happens when I'm doing it for my cookie clicker, the error now says it couldn't find the data.dat file which is in the assets folder which is for sure there. It says when running the application it says cookieclicker.py couldn't find data.dat, so I just need to find where the cookieclicker.py script is located in the applications... idk lol

Comment: Please show the code where `data.dat` is defined/referenced/loaded. This could be a problem with relative paths. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765241/cx-freeze-issue-with-relative-path-on-mac

Comment: It's used to load and store game data e.g. cookies, cps, etc.
Here is where it is used to load data:
`data = pickle.load(open("assets/data.dat", "rb"))`
and here is where it is used to store data:
`pickle.dump(data, open("assets/data.dat", "wb"))`
where data: `data = [cookies, cps, auto_clicker_num]`

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths (see my previous comment)?

Comment: No, I a noob and don't know how to do that, I think that what's I'm looking for though if you would help me with that.